# Get status field based on comparison of date fields between tables

Tags: sql, datetime, join

I need to consolidate two tables specifically by associating task milestones (here being registration and completion) with their statuses at that time.

Example data is below.

`Customers` table:

```
Location   Registration   Completion
AZ         01/15/22       01/30/22
```

`Locations` table:

```
Location    Status_Date     Status
AZ          01/05/22        Pending 
AZ          01/20/22        Approved
```

The desired result using sample data would be:

```
Location   Status_Registration   Status_Completion
AZ         Pending               Approved
```

My initial logic got me as far as linking status dates and milestones by year & month but stuck on how to specifically tie a milestone status to the timeframe that status was valid, i.e. until the status changed in that same location (join along `location`).

Comment: tag with database platform